# NodeJs web crawler file extension handling

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, file-extension

I'm developing a web crawler in nodejs. I've created a unique list of the urls in the website crawle body. But some of them have extensions like jpg,mp3, mpeg ... I want to avoid crawling those who have extensions. Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html and https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for. For example, in website crawle result  "www.abc.com/xyz.jpg", "www.abc.com/xyza.mpeg", "www.abc.com/xyzb.mp3" these links exist. Most of the crawle npms, basically tries to crawle every url you give to them. I dont want to crawle the urls having extensions.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I've checked the Internet. But couldn't find something useful. I asked the question for maybe anyone  in stackoverflow have faced the same problem.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`path.extname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p), from the path module which @MadaraUchiha suggested. You can find out with that function if the url has an extension, and if it doesn't you can go ahead and crawl it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options stick out.

**1) Use `path` to check every URL**

As stated in comments, you can use [`path.extname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p) to check for a file extension.  Thus, this:

```
var test = "http://example.com/images/banner.jpg"
path.extname(test); // '.jpg'
```

This would work, but this feels like you'll wind up having to create a list of file types you can crawl or you must avoid.  That's work.

***Side note*** -- be careful using `path`.  Typically, `url` is your best tool for parsing links because `path` is aimed at files/directories, not urls.  On some systems (Windows), using `path` to manipulate a url can result in drama because of the slashes involved.  Fair warning!

**2) Get the HEAD for each link & see if `content-type` is set to `text/html`**

You may have reasons to avoid making more network calls.  If so, this isn't an option.  But if it is OK to make additional calls, you could grab the HEAD for each link and check the MIME type stored in `content-type`.

Something like this:

```
var headersOptions = {
        method: "HEAD",
        host: "http://example.com",
        path: "/articles/content.html"
    };

var req = http.request(headersOptions, function (res) {
    // you will probably need to also do things like check
    // HTTP status codes so you handle 404s, 301s, and so on

    if (res.headers['content-type'].indexOf("text/html") > -1) {
            // do something like queue the link up to be crawled
            // or parse the link or put it in a database or whatever
        }
    });

req.end();
```

One benefit is that you only grab the HEAD, so even if the file is a gigantic video or something, it won't clog things up.  You get the HEAD, see the `content-type` is a video or whatever, then move along because you aren't interested in that type.

Second, you don't have to keep track of file names because you're using a standard MIME type to differentiate html from other data formats.